# When I run the server in javascript and combine html and tsx formatted files and present them to the server, I get an error in css

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, web3js, ecmascript-5

As I said in the title, I use babel, for this, when I give a jsx formatted side server file , it connects with js, but this time, when I present it fully, a css file integration error occurs. By the way, I use web 3 in my project, but I don't think it's caused by it. For this, I have entered the [enter image description here]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHRY7.png))request call from people who can help me, and I thank the people who are already rolling up their sleeves to help me. (If you can at least cite the article reference, you will help me a lot.)

In the end, what I tried was using babel and a pure node.js sketch to add web 3 static files to my website infrastructure using tsx, js and html and finally web 3 (with infura provider).[text](https://medium.com/@cesarkohl/babel-crash-course-c96d11303250)

Comment: Please, post the error as text, not as an image. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).